# iOS Edit Push Notification Sound From App

Tags: ios, push-notification, xamarin.ios, apple-push-notifications

I would like to know if it is possible to store and edit my push notification sound via my application, without causing my server to send Apple's server, a request for push notification with the alert's name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an Apple doc for this [Apple Developer Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SupportingNotificationsinYourApp.html)

Preparing Custom Alert Sounds

> Local and remote notifications can specify custom alert sounds to be played when the notification is delivered. You can package the audio data in an aiff, wav, or caf file. Because they are played by the system-sound facility, custom sounds must be in one of the following audio data formats:
>
> Linear PCM
>   MA4 (IMA/ADPCM)
>   µLaw
>   aLaw
>   Place custom sound files in your app bundle or in the Library/Sounds folder of your app’s container directory. Custom sounds must be under 30 seconds when played. If a custom sound is over that limit, the default system sound is played instead.
>
> You can use the afconvert tool to convert sounds. For example, to convert the 16-bit linear PCM system sound Submarine.aiff to IMA4 audio in a CAF file, use the following command in the Terminal app:
>
> afconvert /System/Library/Sounds/Submarine.aiff ~/Desktop/sub.caf -d ima4 -f caff -v

Sample for notification payload

```
{
    "aps" : {
         "alert" : "YOUR_TEXT",
         "badge" : YOUR_BADGE_NUMBER,
         "sound" : "YOUR_SOUND_FILE.aiff"
    }
}
```

And your custom sound file should be in inside your project bundle (i.e inside the hierarchy of project) and have Copy items if needed option selected while drag and drop.

Comment: But still, I'm getting the JSON from the ASPN, and therefore the sounds are being saved on the server.
Is it possible to change the sound name of the notification inside the app?

Comment: No it is not. Your custom sound file must be on your iOS project and server only sends the JSON payload with the correct sound file name.